# after create a kedro project -- running kedro install -- SSLerror is coming

Tags: python, pip

I have created a virtual enviroment and then installed kedro on it. Now, created a new kedro project and after that while installing dependencies. I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/flake8/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/flake8/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/flake8/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/flake8/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/flake8/
Could not find a version that matches flake8<4.0,>=3.7.9 (from -r C:\Users\schaudha\wetting_dispersing_agent\src\requirements.in (line 2))
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

Does warning means all packages are installed ?
How to check whether packages are installed or not?
there is no log saying .... package installed ... thereby i suspect they are not installed.

Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is `pip install` error rather than actual package error. You should have a look at how your setup reaches PyPI. I can see that a `flake8` version complying with the requirement `flake8<4.0,>=3.7.9`.
https://pypi.org/project/flake8/3.8.4/